# How to write this SQL statement in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have this SQL statement and my question is how I can write it in laravel 4

```
Select*from tableA cross join tableB
```

Comment: I think there is no `cross join` command in Laravel's Eloquent. But you could use something like `DB::raw()`

Comment: hy Peh... can you give me example for cross join on laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM `tableA` CROSS JOIN `tableB`');
```

> Warning: The above code is not tested.

Comment: tested     DB::select('SELECT * FROM `countries` CROSS JOIN `states`')